# How to add S3 trigger for existing bucket to lambda function in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a template.yml for a lambda function pipeline, this is my template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  ImageUri:
    Type: String
  LambdaName: 
    Type: String
  RoleName:
    Type: String
  BucketName:
    Type: String
    
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain            
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName

  AllowS3ToCallLambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunction
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn

  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Ref RoleName
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
              - lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaName
      PackageType: Image
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 5
      ImageUri: !Ref ImageUri
      Events:
        S3Bucket:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
            Events: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaRole
          - Arn
```

This template contains an S3 event, with the template above it tries to create a new bucket. Is there a way to specify an existing bucket for the trigger?

No matter how much I tried to make `LambdaFunction` resource to use an existing S3 bucket, I failed.

Comment: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/#using-existing-buckets (not that I'm sure this helps from a cloudformation perspective)

Comment: Yeah, actually we don't wanna use serverless. I've seen that link before.

Comment: The template is for serverless, but you don't want to use serverless?

Comment: I mean that only works with serverless.yml, It cannot be used in cloudformation templates.